# Changing state in React clarification

Tags: reactjs, state

I have always known that in React we must never mutate state directly. Yet I see similar things like the example below in many tutorials so many times:

```
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false)

setLiked(!liked)
```

Isn't that mutating it directly? Wouldn't the right way be:

```
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false)

setLiked(prevLiked => !prevLiked)
```

In so many tutorials I see the first example being used, but to my understanding that is precisely mutating the state right? Whereas the second one is the proper way to do it

Comment: No, your first example is not mutating the current state it's passing a new value, `!liked` returns the inverse of `liked`, it does not mutate `liked`

Comment: So in that case, should I use the 1st or 2nd example?

Comment: The first example is a pretty succinct way of toggling a boolean state that most devs would probably use. The second might be used in a callback/memoized function that doesn't get redefined every render so doesn't have access to the latest state

Comment: I'd stick with the second method anytime the state depends on the previous state. You can use the second method in a useCallback without passing the state in the dependency array, because you're telling react how to change the state instead of what to set it as.

Answer (score 0):

1 - **the first one**  `setLiked(!liked)`  is using the ***Logical NOT (!)*** and it is not mutating the `liked state` it just returns a value based on that state.

2 - **In the second one** `setLiked(prevLiked => !prevLiked)`  you call `setLiked` with a callback that takes the prevLiked parameter, And return the new value of the liked state as the return value.

So which one to use? they're both doing the same job with no difference